# ASP.NET MVC 6 using IIS to develop without publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way to develop an ASP.NET MVC 6 beta 8 application on IIS without having the need to publish the application?

After install the httpPlatform module I am able to point IIS to a published application.

But how can yo point IIS to say your visual studio solution wwwroot so you can develop and see the changes you make without having the need to publish?

Is this no longer possible like how it you could develop asp.net MVC 5 apps?
For development is IIS Express and Kestrel the preferred way now?

**Update:**
I've tried to run both commands like the vs.net debugger shows but I still get bad gateway
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure about IIS, but you can point IIS Express to a directory and run that as a site. Check out [this page](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line) for details, way at the bottom. Here's an example: `iisexpress /path:c:\myapp\`. You can then browse to localhost:8080 (uses port 8080 by defualt).

Comment: Thanks for that, yes IIS Express works but the same doesn't work for IIS for some reason unless I publish the website

Comment: I'm virtually certain IIS can't be used for local development anymore. Fortunately, IIS Express has proved reliable and with a couple months under my belt I haven't run into any differences. These days the only time I deploy to local IIS is if I run into a deployment issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is interested to get this working so that you have an edit and continue experience and don't have to manually build or publish your site and work against your source code:
https://github.com/tuespetre/dnx-watch-iis

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html).

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 for developing MVC 6 (beta8) applications, and do not have the problem you describe. An MVC 6 application has a file that by default  points to wwwroot folder (I do not remember now the filename), so you should not have problem in change code and hit F5 to see the changes, without publishing.

Comment: I'll see if I can find this file because I'm struggling to get this all working. Please have a look at my updated question for screenshots

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1000) I found a guy who had the same problem and solved it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this issue you have been a great help