# IIS Express command line ASP.NET MVC 6 beta 8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an ASP.NET MVC 6 beta 8 application and when I click debug in Visual Studio 2015 I can see IIS Express and the site works properly.

But if I try and launch IIS Express from the command line pointing to the right applicationHost.config file I get and error, does something else need to be added?

**C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /config:D:\Programming\Projects\WebApplication1.vs\config\applicationHost.config /siteid:3**

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
>
> There was a connection error while trying to route the request.
>
> Most likely causes: •The CGI application did not return a valid set of
>   HTTP errors. •A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to
>   process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.
>
> Things you can try: •Use DebugDiag to troubleshoot the CGI
>   application. •Determine if a proxy or gateway is responsible for this
>   error.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    httpPlatformHandler
>
> Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler    httpPlatformHandler
>
> Error Code    0x80070002

Comment: Not sure if this needs to be installed for iisexpress, but it is needed by full IIS, http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler

Comment: Thanks Despertar I have installed this for IIS

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error you are when trying to run it through full IIS. The only way I've got it to work outside visual studio is publishing the web application, then running C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project_name\approot\web.cmd which uses the new Kestrel web server. It sounds like they want to have the Kestrel web server do all the hosting and if IIS is used it will treat it more like CGI and have it generate the HTTP response which it returns. Other alternatives would be doing an nginx proxy pass (I'm sure IIS has a way to do this as well).

Answer (score 7):

I would:

- hit Debug in VS
- go to the Task manager -> Details
- right click header row -> Select columns
- select "Command line"
- observe

In my case the command line is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"  /config:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myproject.vs\config\applicationhost.config" /site:"myproject" /apppool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint I will definitely try this out. Do you know if it's possible to point IIS to your visual studio solutions wwwroot and be able to debug in a similar manner? I've asked the question here for more details: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291084/asp-net-mvc-6-using-iis-to-develop-without-publish

Comment: I'm not sure but I was always under the impression that you have to publish the app first. I thought that the VS also does the Publish behind the scenes...

Comment: > If I run:

dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin>dnx -p "D:\Programming\Projects\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2" web on it's own

Comment: If I run this command, I can see it works on http://localhos:5000/
dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin>dnx -p "D:\Programming\Projects\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2" web

But running the iisexpress which is on port 26850 and this command together I still get bad gateway problem. So I'm not sure how the 2 tie in together. Ultimately I would like to get my IIS exxperience back to how I used to with previous versions of vs.net

Comment: neither am i. it seems that you're not the only one trying to solve this. i recommend subscribing to the following issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1012 hopefully someone from the asp.net team will provide more insight. in the meantime you can use kestrel to self-host the app...