# Run ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API using IIS Express without Building the App on Windows

Tags: asp.net-core, build, iis-express

Is there a way to run an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API using IIS Express without building the application to build folder on Windows (i.e. just like `dotnet run` builds in memory)?

Comment: You can only do that in Visual Studio as it knows how to integrate IIS Express with your source code, but you cannot do that on your own. Some out-of-date hints can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Comment: I have read the article. Would you please elaborate more on why it is impossible to do without VS? I am using VS Code with dotnet cli and I do not want to build the app everytime to run IIS Express.

Comment: In short, the VS component `VSIISExeLauncher` is the key here to enable VS/IIS Express integration with .NET Core project source code. If you want similar functionality with VSCode alone, then you have to write your own `VSIISExeLauncher`, which won't be an easy task.

Comment: When I read the article, it seems that VS is supplying the project entry DLL and path to iieexpress.exe. I thought VSIISExeLuncher is only there to attach VS debugger. What does VSIISExeLuncher actually do here? It seems VS build the project after all to disk before running IIS Express.

Comment: Does this SO thread help achieve your requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899494/launch-iis-express-to-run-asp-net-core-apps

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express is a Windows only server, so no. You can build and run the self-hosted (Kestrel) version of the apps on non-Windows platforms. It ends up being just dotnet run.

Comment: But this question is about Windows.